# Passing dynamic value as input to mongo and update

Tags: mongodb

Hi I want to get a orgName value as input parameter via pipeline and pass it to the findOneAndUpdate function in Mongodb. My ask is to find a orgID based on input orgName and update flag to false . Can someone help on this?

I tried like below option and it worked.  But only via hardcoding the orgname like XOXO works.

I want this to be dynamic based on input value as parameter

```
db.reg.findOneAndUpdate(
   { organisationName: "XOXO" },
   { $set: { isSuccessful: true } },
   { returnNewDocument : true }
)
```